# MS Visual C++ Starting a function by clicking a button without blocking a dialog

Tags: c++, button, mfc, event-handling

I've created a dialog based MFC application on MS Visual Studio 2013. To the dialog, I've added ActiveX elements and some other list elements to show text output. One of the buttons with the ID `IDC_BUTTONLAUNCH` calls a function like

```
void CpiezcamDlg::OnBnClickedButtonlaunch()
{
  SweepAndImage();
}
```

The function `SweepAndImage()`, which is a member of the class `CpiezcamDlg` and a bit more expensive (it takes about 10 sec). The function also calls updates to the list elements. There is also a `Sleep` function inside of `SweepAndImage()`. The result is that during the call of this function, the complete dialog is "blocked" and doesn't react (which makes sense). I've just started with MFC this week so my knowledge is rather limited. I tried to do

```
void CpiezcamDlg::OnBnClickedButtonlaunch()
{
#pragma omp parallel
  {
  #pragma omp single nowait
      SweepAndImage();
  }
}
```

to sort of "fork" the function into another thread. Since there's an implicit barrier at the end of the `omp` pragma, this doesn't work. I guess I need some sort event handler that is running in the background of my application and see if that button was clicked. Any kind of help or link is appreciated. If more information is needed, I'll add it.

Comment: Why not use a lightweight `std::thread` or alternatively `CreateThread` (if you want to stick with WinAPI functions and don't have C++11)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP uses fork and thread to do work. It will not really do what you wish here.

MFC's GUI is running on the main thread. SweepAndImage will be run in a separate thread however OnBnClickedButtonlaunch will block waiting for SweepAndImage to return from doing work and then it will continue on. Because the main thread has been blocked updates to the GUI will also halt. Windows/MFC has a hidden window message pump that is abstracted away. That pump relies on event handlers (ie. your button press method) not blocking for too long so that the pump can continue on with the next event in the queue.

Since you are using MFC, MFC does have support for multithreading. I would recommend starting with this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/975t8ks0.aspx)

What you can do is create a new thread (see the article above) in your button handler that spawns off some work. That will allow the main thread to continue immediately and continue processing windows events in its pump.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I'm looking for: [Multithreading: Creating Worker Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69644x60.aspx) With an example!

Comment: @MichaelPetch, OpenMP would work for this using tasks if MSVC support OpenMP 3.0 but MSVC only supports OpenMP 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

To be complete:
Define

```
UINT SweepAndImage(LPVOID pParam)
```

Call it like

```
AfxBeginThread(SweepAndImage, NULL);
```

Instead of `return 0`, use

```
AfxEndThread(0, TRUE); /* or (1, ...) for return 1 */
```

to exit `SweepAndImage`